# Inherit multiple variables inside a anonymous function

Tags: php

Is there a way to inherit multiple variables from inside a anonymous function? I am aware of just inheriting an array but I am curious if there is another way to inherit variables other than using arrays.

Perhaps something like:

```
function($arg) use ($inherited1, $inherited2){
    // access the $inherited1 and $inherited2 variables directly 
}
```

Comment: Simply a big NO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
   $inherited1 = '1';
        $inherited2 = '2';
        $example = function($arg) use (&$inherited1, &$inherited2){
            // access the $inherited1 and $inherited2 variables directly 
        var_dump($arg . $inherited1 . $inherited2);
        }
        $example('arg');
```